# List wont display properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I am trying to display data on two different fragments from viewmodels: Recent Races and Upcoming Races. i wrote a filter function to filter the races that are yet to start and the ones that finished. Upcoming races works perfectly, when there is a change in api endpoint it removes the race from upcoming races list. but the problem is that it wont add it to recent races.

here is my code in RecentRacesViewModel

```
private fun getDetails() {
        getRaceDetailsUseCase().onEach { result ->
            when (result) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    val filteredList = result.data.filter {
                        val time = Calendar.getInstance().time
                        val formatterCurrentTime = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                        val formatterNow = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
                        val currentTime = formatterCurrentTime.format(time)
                        val dateNow = LocalDate.parse(currentTime, formatterNow)

                        val dateFromModel = it.date
                        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
                        val date = LocalDate.parse(dateFromModel, formatter)

                        dateNow >= date
                    }
                    _state1.value = Resource.Success(filteredList)
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    _state1.value = Resource.Error("woops!")
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    _state1.value = Resource.Loading(true)
                }
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

thanks for help

Edit: adding the UseCase:

```
class RaceDetailsUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: RaceResultsRepository
) {
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<Resource<List<RaceDomain>>> = flow {
        try {
            emit(Resource.Loading(true))
            val raceData = repository.GetRaceResultsRepository()
            emit(Resource.Success(raceData))
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            Log.d("tag", "error")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.d("tag", "io error")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `getRaceDetailsUseCase()` look like? Because if I understand correctly, you don't get updates if there is a change in backend?

Comment: check the answer, pasted the code there.

Comment: That's not how you update/add context to the question. There is "Edit" button on a question.

Comment: got you. updated the question